# How can I use sys.argv in Python

Tags: macos, google-colaboratory, argv, sys

I am runnung this code from a paper:

```
import sys
fi = open(sys.argv[1])
output_feature = open(sys.argv[2],"w")
output_group = open(sys.argv[3],"w")
```

When I run this code in `Colab` I face this error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-f'

and if I run the code in `mac Os` I face this error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you invoking this from a shell as an executable/python script? If that's the case, can you show the complete command? If not, then the OS X exception is caused by `sys.argv` having only one item in it (hence the index error)

Comment: The error you face in macOS likely comes from the fact that you give no command line arguments when running the code.

Comment: How can I give command line arguments with correct values to make my script work? I need values for argument 1 and 2 and 3.

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in the comments of the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` represents a list of command line arguments you have given when running the python script. Say we put the code from your example in a script 'script.py', you could run it from the command line as follows:

```
python script.py argument_1 argument_2 argument_3
```

The reason you need the 3 additional arguments is that you try to access 3 additional elements in `sys.argv` in your code (indices 1,2,3). The first index (0) is the script itself, so script.py in this case. Also note that the argument names above are arbitrarily chosen. If you would run the code in any of the following ways:

```
python script.py 
python script.py argument_1
python script.py argument_1 argument_2
```

you will get the following error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

because `sys.argv` will be a list that contains less than 4 elements.

Comment: Thank you. What should I write for argument 1 and 2 and 3?  I mean how can I know which value is true for them and make my script to work correctly?

Comment: Judging by your initial script, argument_1 should be the name of an input_file your script reads whereas argument_2 and argument_3 are some new files you are writing, so I suspect (given the information I have) that you can chose any name for them.

Comment: Would you take a look at the codes in this link- an actual example in the middle of the paper. May be you can better help me with the values of arguments 1,2,3.https://mlexplained.com/2019/05/27/learning-to-rank-explained-with-code/

Comment: Looking at the link you sent me, I see that the solution is literally provided below the code snippet. For example "python trans_data.py train.txt mq2008.train mq2008.train.group". I am not sure what could go wrong. Also, if the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: yes, you are right. I could pass this step. But for the next step, how can load the data into memory using the following code? It seems that "load_svmlight_file" is not defined by the program!!

    x_train, y_train = load_svmlight_file("mq2008.train")

Comment: You asked a specific question, I answered it. This is not the place to expect a line-by-line explanation of a book. If you have another specific enough question, other than "x does not work", that has not been answered before, feel free to post another question. But I doubt this would be the case at this point. Try to google the solution first.