# passing argument to boto3 e2 start script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

any idea how I can modify this to passing the instance id as argument instead of putting it in the script?

```
import boto3

def stop_instance(instance_id):
    ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name="us-west-1")
    response = ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
    print(response)

stop_instance()
```

Comment: Add [command line parsing](https://realpython.com/comparing-python-command-line-parsing-libraries-argparse-docopt-click/), e.g. using argparse or click.

Comment: If you are wanting to stop an instance from the command-line, you could instead use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command: `aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids <instance-id>`

Comment: I want to use python. infact i want to have just one script to start and stop instances

Answer (score 0):

If your objective if to stop all EC2 instances via Python script, you can first call the [describe-instances method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) to dynamically build a list of all the running EC2 instances (pull id values based on the state property = running). From there you can pass that list into your function to stop them all, as the [stop-instances method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.stop_instances) can handle a list of ids.

Comment: not stop all. I want to have an ad=hoc python script to stop an ec2 instance by passing the instance Id as an argument. like so python3 shutdown_ec2.py instance_id

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the endgame - use the sys module (sys.argv) to pass the instance id value into the script

Comment: i need to import sys and argparse?

Comment: Yep.. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212110/how-can-i-use-sys-argv-in-python

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
import boto3
import sys
import argparse
instance_id = sys.argv[1]

def stop_instance(instance_id):
    ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name="us-west-1")
    response = ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
    print(response)

stop_instance(instance_id)
```

then i ran it with python3 stop_ec2.py instance-id

Comment: when i run it without arguments: it shows this.....................

Comment: python3 stop_ec2.py        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stop_ec2.py", line 4, in <module>
    instance_id = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: is it as expected